# MS Access - Row_Number Partition by

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do the equivalent of row_number partition by in MS Access.

I have a currency table in access called FX_Rates.

This table has a currency field, an exchange rate field and a date field.
I want to insert a count of records into a field that will basically show if there are duplicates in this table because I then want to delete out the duplicate values so anything with a count >1.

So for example if I have the following data:

```
Currency    ExchangeRate    Date
EUR         1               31/12/2019
EUR         1               31/12/2019
GBP         1.1             31/12/2019
GBP         1.5             31/12/2019
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
Currency    ExchangeRate    Date            Count
EUR         1               31/12/2019      1
EUR         1               31/12/2019      2
GBP         1.1             31/12/2019      1
GBP         1.5             31/12/2019      1
```

From looking this up online I have come up with the following code:

```
Call RunSQL("INSERT INTO FX_Rates_New  " & _
    "SELECT " & _
    " t1.Currency, t1.Exchange_Rate, t1.Date_of_Report" & _
    ",COUNT(*) AS Count_of_Record " & _
    "FROM FX_Rates AS t1 " & _
    "INNER JOIN FX_Rates AS t2 ON t1.Currency = t2.Currency AND t1.Date_of_Report = t2.Date_of_Report " & _
    "GROUP BY " & _
    " t1.Currency, t1.Exchange_Rate, t1.Date_of_Report " & _
    "ORDER BY t1.Date_of_Report, t1.Currency ")
```

However the above is just inserting unique records into a new table and the count is coming in as 4 for items I know there is only 2 of.

Ideally I want to update my current table with the count next to each as I demonstrated above. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
If anyone is looking to do something similar and in a simple way I actually ended up using the below code, After June7's response I added in an AutoNum field which made it much easier to accomplish what I wanted:

```
Call RunSQL("DELETE * FROM FX_Rates " & _
    "WHERE FX_Rates.ID NOT IN ( " & _
    "SELECT Min(FX_Rates.ID) AS ID " & _
    "FROM FX_Rates " & _
    "GROUP BY  " & _
    "FX_Rates.Currency, FX_Rates.Date) ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a unique record identifier - an autonumber field (ID in below query) should serve. Consider:

```
SELECT FX_Rates.Currency, FX_Rates.Exchange_Rate, FX_Rates.Date_of_Report, 
  (SELECT Count(*) AS HowMany
   FROM FX_Rates AS Dupe
   WHERE Dupe.ID < FX_Rates.ID AND Dupe.Currency=FX_Rates.Currency 
   AND Dupe.Exchange_Rate=FX_Rates.Exchange_Rate
   AND Dupe.Date_of_Report=FX_Rates.Date_of_Report)+1 AS GrpSeq
FROM FX_Rates;
```

For more info, review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: Hi thanks or getting back to me, I've tied this and it's not working for me as I have no field called ID in my data. IS there a reason you included the following: WHERE Dupe.ID < FX_Rates.ID

Comment: What I posted works for me. You can easily add autonumber field to table. ID is autonumber field.

Comment: Thank you, I added in the autonum and it works fine now. Appreciate the help.